# Dynamic Projection using DynamicExpressionParser ParseLambda

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-core, projection

I'm trying to convert some code that creates a dynamic projection from .Net 4.5 to .Net Core 3; I have the following code in .Net 4.5

```
var e = DynamicExpression.ParseLambda(
                typeof(MyModel),
                typeof (object),
                "new(Id as id)");
```

ParseLambda is not available on DynamicExpression in .Net Core 3, so I changed the code to:

```
var e = DynamicExpressionParser.ParseLambda(
            typeof(MyModel),
            typeof (object),
            "new(Id as id)");
```

But this results in a null reference exception with the following stack trace

```
   at System.Linq.Dynamic.Core.Parser.ExpressionParser.CreateNewExpression(List`1 properties, List`1 expressions, Type newType)
   at System.Linq.Dynamic.Core.Parser.ExpressionParser.ParseNew()
   at System.Linq.Dynamic.Core.Parser.ExpressionParser.ParseIdentifier()
   at System.Linq.Dynamic.Core.Parser.ExpressionParser.ParsePrimary()
   at System.Linq.Dynamic.Core.Parser.ExpressionParser.ParseUnary()
   at System.Linq.Dynamic.Core.Parser.ExpressionParser.ParseMultiplicative()
   at System.Linq.Dynamic.Core.Parser.ExpressionParser.ParseAdditive()
   at System.Linq.Dynamic.Core.Parser.ExpressionParser.ParseShiftOperator()
   at System.Linq.Dynamic.Core.Parser.ExpressionParser.ParseComparisonOperator()
   at System.Linq.Dynamic.Core.Parser.ExpressionParser.ParseLogicalAndOrOperator()
   at System.Linq.Dynamic.Core.Parser.ExpressionParser.ParseIn()
   at System.Linq.Dynamic.Core.Parser.ExpressionParser.ParseAndOperator()
   at System.Linq.Dynamic.Core.Parser.ExpressionParser.ParseOrOperator()
   at System.Linq.Dynamic.Core.Parser.ExpressionParser.ParseLambdaOperator()
   at System.Linq.Dynamic.Core.Parser.ExpressionParser.ParseNullCoalescingOperator()
   at System.Linq.Dynamic.Core.Parser.ExpressionParser.ParseConditionalOperator()
   at System.Linq.Dynamic.Core.Parser.ExpressionParser.Parse(Type resultType, Boolean createParameterCtor)
   at System.Linq.Dynamic.Core.DynamicExpressionParser.ParseLambda(ParsingConfig parsingConfig, Boolean createParameterCtor, ParameterExpression[] parameters, Type resultType, String expression, Object[] values)
   at System.Linq.Dynamic.Core.DynamicExpressionParser.ParseLambda(Boolean createParameterCtor, Type itType, Type resultType, String expression, Object[] values)
   at System.Linq.Dynamic.Core.DynamicExpressionParser.ParseLambda(Type itType, Type resultType, String expression, Object[] values)
```

The code works fine when the expression is "Id == 0" or any other comparison, but I cannot get the "new" expression to work...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Passing typeof(object) as the result type works with the .Net 4.5 implementation of ParseLambda, but after reviewing the System.Linq.Dynamic.Core source code, I found that ParseLambda can take a result type of null. The following code works as expected in .Net Core 3.

```
var e = DynamicExpressionParser.ParseLambda(
          typeof(MyModel),  // itType
          null,             // resultType
          "new(Id as id)"); // expression
```

https://github.com/StefH/System.Linq.Dynamic.Core/blob/master/src/Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DynamicLinq/EFDynamicQueryableExtensions.cs

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you're using the [System.Linq.Dynamic.Core](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Linq.Dynamic.Core/).

If that's the case, you need **ensure that the output type gets a property of `id`**. Your code won't work because your output type is **`object`** . As an **`object` doesn't get a `id` property**, it fails.

Because of a similar reason, you need also to **ensure the input type gets a property of `Id`**.

The trick is always using consistent properties. For example, let's say you have two types :

```
public class MyInput                  // input 
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}

public class MyOutput                // output
{
    public int id { get; set; }
}
```

You could parse a string as below :

```
var e = DynamicExpressionParser.ParseLambda(
    typeof(MyInput),                 // input type
    typeof(MyOutput),                // output type
    "new (Id as id)");               // initialize properties

// test
MyOutput o = e.Compile().DynamicInvoke(new MyInput() { Id = 123 }) as MyOutput;
Console.WriteLine(o.id);     // outputs 123
```

Comment: The output type will depend on which properties are in the expression, it could be as simple as "new(Id as id)", but it will likely be more complex, like "new(Id as id, Company.Name as companyName, ...)" Why can't it simply be of type object like it was in .Net 4.5?

Comment: @Failwyn  You could also do that in .NET Core too. Please do give it a try. By the way, it's not about complexity, but about type safe.

Comment: The exact code that works in .Net 4 doesn't work in .Net Core, I'm trying to figure out why; what should the output type be for a projection? When you do a projection in Linq, there is no concrete output type, if it can't be object, what should it be?

Comment: @Failwyn According to my test, the above code works both on `.NET Framework` and `.NET Core`. Are you serious about there will be no concrete output type? There will be always a type there, at least an anonymous type. If you want to create a "dynamic", please try `ExpandoObject` -- I haven't tested it, but I guess it should work as your expected.

Comment: The above code, meaning your code, or my code?  I can't supply a concrete class for the output as you have done in your code, the output will basically be an anonymous type since the expression can be any subset of the original type. An anonymous type isn't concrete, there's no way to supply its type to the output type parameter of this function, I'm just trying to find out why the code no longer works after moving to .Net core, there's no need to be condescending.

Edit: typeof(ExpandoObject) results in the same null reference exception.

Comment: @Failwyn  Glad to hear you have solved this question by yourself.  No offending. I'm so sorry if my poor English make you think I'm trying to "be condersending". I never mean to do that. I also test the `ExpandoObject`, it does throw a null reference exception as you said. Your answer that uses `null` as an argument works fine for me.